# firebase temporarily sending "There is no user record"?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, passport.js

I'm trying to make a simple web application and trying to implement google authentication(login) using passport and store the user in firebase authentication.

So, in the passport middleware what i do is check if the user is authenticated.
if yes then pass the user to the `passport.serializeUser(user)` else create the user in firebase authentication. and then pass the user to `passport.serializeUser(user)`

here is a pseudo code -

```
if (user.authenticated){

   done(null, user)

} else {

let promise = {'uid': user.uid, 'name': user.displayName, 'picture':user.photos[0].value};

   firebase.auth().createUser({
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.name,
            photoURL: user.picture

        });
   console.log('i have submitted the user')
   done(null, promise)
 }
```

everything is going cool the `passport.serializeUser()` gets and the user calls `done(null, user.uid)`.

the problem hits when the `passport.deserializeUser()`.

i dont do any fancy there but just get the user from the firebase by using `firebase.auth().getUser(id)` where it gives me an error.

here is my code for `passport.deserializeUser()`.

```
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => { // when we get a request

    console.log(`deser id ${id}`); // it shows the id we passed in serialize

    firebase.auth().getUser(id).then(  // gives an error T_T ?
        (user) => {
            console.log(`deser data ${user}`); // IT SHOULD GO HERE

            done(null, user)

        }).catch((error) => { // it goes here and throws an error at me 

        console.log(`here is the error on deser ${error}`);
       // here is the error on deser Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier.

    });

});
```

the magic happens after some time when the `passport.deserealizeUser()` gets called again at now for some reason it *doesn't* throw a error at me.

here is the console log..

```
i have submitted the user
ser // i do this call in passport.serializeUser()
deser id "someid"
here is the error on deser Error: There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier. 
deser id "someid"
deser data [object Object]
```

my question is that why does the firebase being delayed?
is it because of the reason that first time the firebase didn't loaded and the second time it loaded and was successful to find the user?

but what could be the reason for that?
any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright guys So, after a big nap I've found out what I did wrong, i wasn't handling the promise from the..

```
firebase.auth().createUser({
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.name,
            photoURL: user.picture

        });
```

so what i did is like ..

```
firebase.auth().createUser({
            uid: user.uid,
            displayName: user.name,
            photoURL: user.picture

        }).then((user) => {
        done(null, user);
});
```

certainly it requires some time to process the user in the `auth()` ..

that is why.

***ALWAYS USE PROMISES.***